# Server runs locally but crashes on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I deployed my server on Heroku but when I make any requests it returns a "500 Internal Server" error. It runs fine locally though. Could anyone help figure out what's going on?

When I check my logs this is what I'm getting.

```
2021-06-08T18:43:09.715406+00:00 app[web.1]: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.90.138.215", user "detmvsbueicsez", database "da9nlve42hcp91", SSL off
```

Repo Link: https://github.com/zcason/Restaurant-Review-Server
Live App: https://restaurant-review-phi.vercel.app/

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to add more important information to this question: provide a minimum working example, what have you tried, etc

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with your code's compatibility with Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here on [Heroku help](https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres), this indicate that there was a failed authentication attempt to the database, so the connection couldn't be established. This can happen because of different reasons.

In your case i suspect it's something related to not using ssl.
So after taking a look on the code provided in the github repo i noticed you are using `knex` and getting the `connection string` from `.env`

**Try this :**

- Just add this `?ssl=true`  and append it to the end of `DATABASE_URL` in your `.env` file.
- Edit your server.js (i didn't take a good look at the code so you need to add this `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` in your connection config) :

```
const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        connectionString: DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
    }
});
```

- Also make sure you're using the wright user and password and database name etc

**OR Alternatively** :

Run  this command `heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify` in terminal to omit the ssl configuration object and set `PGSSLMODE` to `no-verify`

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it out right now.

Comment: NO.. this will push your `.env` to the github repo and your creds will be exposed witch is not good. the `.gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. from commits pushes etc

Comment: you can read more about `.gitignore` here https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Also does this answer solve your problem, if so please upvote and mark it as accepted

Comment: No, it didn't. So I added a line to my config file that was similar to what you're telling me to do `DATABASE_URL: process.env.DATABASE_URL + (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '?ssl=true' : '') || "myLocalDataBaseUrl " ` and now Im get this in my heroku logs. `2021-06-08T21:31:18.468956+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate`

Comment: ........................................................................

Comment: The alternative way worked! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: you're welcome,if you want you can accept the answer so the question will be marked as answered